# Numpy genfromtxt issue with datetime with multiple columns

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I am having an issue of having two datetime columns when I want one. 
I am trying to load data into a numpy array using the following

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
def load_data_from_file( filename):
    timeconverter = lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
    data = np.genfromtxt(filename,
                         delimiter=[' '],
                          dtype=['object','object','float',
                                 'float','float','float'],
                         converters={1:timeconverter})
```

My dataset file looks like this:

```
2015/03/19 20:01:00.000 92.339302 0.694200 -0.013000 0.033000
```

I can't figure out how to combine "2015/03/19" date column and the "20:01:00.000" time column to form a datetime column. I've tried using space delimited importing but the floats may have negative values so that idea didn't work either. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have to use numpy? would pandas be OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to preprocess the text lines, massaging the 1st 2 strings into a form that `np.datetime64` can handle:

```
def foo(s):
    strings = s.split()
    date, minutes = strings[:2]
    date = date.replace('/','-')+'T'+minutes+'Z'
    return ' '.join([date]+strings[2:])

txt=['2015-03-19T20:01:00.000Z 92.339302 0.694200 -0.013000 0.033000']

foo(txt[0])
# '2015-03-19T20:01:00.000 92.339302 0.694200 -0.013000 0.033000'

A=np.genfromtxt([foo(t) for t in txt],dtype='datetime64[ms],f,f,f,f')
```

producing:

```
array((datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 19, 20, 1), 92.33930206298828, 0.6941999793052673, -0.013000000268220901, 0.032999999821186066), 
      dtype=[('f0', '<M8[ms]'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4'), ('f3', '<f4'), ('f4', '<f4')])
```

Timezone assumptions with `np.datetime64` can be confusing.  I added `Z` in `foo` to make UTC explicit.  But display may still use the local time:

```
A['f0'][()]
# numpy.datetime64('2015-03-19T13:01:00.000-0700')
```

[convertion of datetime to numpy datetime without timezone info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616292/convertion-of-datetime-to-numpy-datetime-without-timezone-info)

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use pandas this would be trivial to load:

```
In [4]:

import pandas as pd
import io
t="""2015/03/19 20:01:00.000 92.339302 0.694200 -0.013000 0.033000"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep='\s+',parse_dates=[[0,1]], header=None)
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 5 columns):
0_1    1 non-null datetime64[ns]
2      1 non-null float64
3      1 non-null float64
4      1 non-null float64
5      1 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(4)
memory usage: 48.0 bytes
In [5]:

df
Out[5]:
                  0_1          2       3      4      5
0 2015-03-19 20:01:00  92.339302  0.6942 -0.013  0.033
```